# Java parsing byte

Tags: java, byte

I have a byte b

byte has 8 bits

```
bits for single byte

0 = status
1 = locale
2 = AUX
bits (3 & 4) relay
 1. 0 (hence 00) still
 2. 1 (hence 01) noStill
 3. 2 (hence 10) stationed
 4. 3 (hence 11) slow
5 = message;
6 = stuff
7 = moreStuff
```

how would I parse bits 3 and 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
switch ((b>>3)&3){
  case 0: return still;
  case 1: return noStill;
  case 2: return stationed;
  case 3: return slow
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `BitSet` class to retrieve specific bits from a byte value:

```
public static BitSet fromByte(byte b)
{
    BitSet bits = new BitSet(8);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        bits.set(i, (b & 1) == 1);
        b >>= 1;
    }
    return bits;
}
```

By using the above method, you can get the `BitSet` representation of your byte and get specific bits:

```
byte b = ...; // byte value.
System.out.println(fromByte(b).get(2));  // printing bit #3
System.out.println(fromByte(b).get(3));  // printing bit #4
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
    boolean still = (b & 0xC) == 0x0;
    boolean noStill = (b & 0xC) == 0x4;  
    boolean stationed = (b & 0xC) == 0x8; 
    boolean slow = (b & 0xC) == 0xC;
```

Comment: Can you explain what the bit anding is doing here and why we are anding it by 0xC. Thanks

Comment: full byte may be 0b11001100 or 0b01001100 or other, but after & 0xC it becomes 0b00001100, only bit 3 and 4 are left, and we now we can analize our byte by comparing it with 0000 1000 0100 0000

Answer (score 1):

`bitwise AND` (`&`)

Example:

```
 myByte & 0x08 --> myByte & 00001000 --> 0 if and only if bit 4 of "myByte" is 0; 0x08 otherwise
```

Comment: can you demonstrate in a small snippet. Thank you greatly

Comment: I already did. I am not going to do your code for you. You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right, you want the bits in `b[3]` and `b[4]` to be parsed like this:

```
00 = still
01 = noStill
10 = stationed
11 = slow
```

I'd do this:

```
if(b[3] == 0) { // still or noStill
    if(b[4] == 0) {/* still */}
    if(b[4] == 1) {/* noStill */}
}
if(b[3] == 1) { // stationed or slow
    if(b[4] == 0) {/* stationed */}
    if(b[4] == 1) {/* slow */}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in [JBBP](https://code.google.com/p/java-binary-block-parser/) it  looks like

```
@Bin(type = BinType.BIT) class Parsed { byte status; byte locale; byte aux; byte relay; byte message; byte stuff; byte moreStuff;}
final Parsed parsed = JBBPParser.prepare("bit status; bit locale; bit aux; bit:2 relay; bit message; bit stuff; bit moreStuff;").parse(new byte[]{12}).mapTo(Parsed.class);
```